# unable to retrieve data from Firebase using Fragments in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, data-retrieval

Hy! I am trying to retrieve data from `Firebase` but unable to show the pictures and names of categories on the fragment layout. I can't understand whether its Firebase error or Layout error because on selecting fragment `imageview` or `textview` are also not been shown. This is the code from categories fragment in which `recyclerview` is used in fragment layout XML file.

```
public class CategoriesFragment extends Fragment {

View myfragment;
RecyclerView listCategory;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category,CategoryViewHolder> adapter;

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference categories;





public static CategoriesFragment newInstance(){
    CategoriesFragment categoriesFragment = new CategoriesFragment();
    return categoriesFragment;
}



@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    categories = database.getReference("Category");


}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    myfragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories,container,false);

    listCategory = (RecyclerView)myfragment.findViewById(R.id.listcategory);
    listCategory.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(container.getContext());
    listCategory.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    loadCategories();

    return myfragment;
}

private void loadCategories() {

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, CategoryViewHolder>(
            Category.class,
            R.layout.category_layout,
            CategoryViewHolder.class,
            categories
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder viewHolder, final Category model, int position) {

            viewHolder.category_name.setText(model.getName());
            Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load(model.getImage())
                    .into(viewHolder.category_image);

            viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),String.format("%s|%s",adapter.getRef(position).getKey(),model.getName()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }

            });



        }
    };

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listCategory.setAdapter(adapter);

}`
```

Comment: Does populateViewHolder get called?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It's not giving any error, but nothing is shown in categories fragment. Not even the image view or text area i created in XML file